# memory operand not allowed in context, Problem with array size while copying variable to array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to copy value of al into array (var) but it gives me error:

**"memory operand not allowed in context"**

I have no idea why it doesn't work, I am using movsx to copy small size into big size..

```
.data

var word 1000h, 2000h, 3000h

.code

mov al, 60h ;mov 60h to al
movsx var, al ;mov value of al to var
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movsx` exists only in the form `movsx reg, r/m` with a couple of different combinations for different sizes, but no "reverse" form. So it cannot be used to directly write to memory, though it can be used to read from memory.

So in a general context, you could sign-extend into a register and then store that value.

In this case you could use a normal `mov` with a 16bit immediate.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Hang i.e. `mov ax,60h` `mov [var],ax` ... or if `AL` is mandatory as source of value, then `movsx ax,al` `mov [var],ax` (or any other 16b register like `movsx bx,al` `mov [var],bx`, whichever you can spare for extended value).  - BTW, you must always check instruction reference guide for your target CPU to see, if some instruction does exist. You can't just make up some instruction by "common sense" or "logic", the instructions in CPU are hard-wired by its design, and either they exist or they do not, even if one would expect them.